# Перевод на работу с GSON

Tags: java, json

Вот исходный код:

```
public static ArrayList<ShopItem> parseJsonShops(String json)
        throws JSONException {
    if (json == null) {
        return null;
    }
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    if (jsonObject.has(Constants.RESPONSE)) {
        ArrayList<ShopItem> shopItems = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray(Constants.RESPONSE);

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            jsonObject = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
            shopItems.add(getShopItem(jsonObject));
        }
        return shopItems;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Вот тот код который написал я, и при котором в приложении я ловлю два креша

```
public static ArrayList<ShopItem> parseJsonShops(String json)
        throws JSONException {
    JSONObject jsObj = new JSONObject(json);
    if (jsObj.has(Constants.RESPONSE)) {
        json = jsObj.optJSONArray(Constants.RESPONSE).toString();
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = builder.create();
        Type parseJsonShops = new TypeToken<List<ShopItem>>() {
        }
                .getType();
        ArrayList<ShopItem> shopItems = gson.fromJson(json, parseJsonShops);
        return shopItems;
    }
    return null;
}
```

В приложении выпадают следующие ошибки

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

и

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
```

Как их исправить?